# R: Calculate mean by column in a list of dataframes using pipes %>% in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to get better in using pipes `%>%` in `dplyr` package. I understand that the whole point of using pipes (`%>%`) is that it replaces the first argument in a function by the one connected by pipe. That is, in this example:

```
area = rep(c(3:7), 5) + rnorm(5)
```

Pipes

```
area %>% 
  mean
```

equal normal function

```
`mean(area)`.
```

---

My problem is when it gets to a dataframe. I would like to split dataframe in a list of dataframes, and than calculate means per `area` columns. But, I can't figure out how to call the column instead of the dataframe?

I know that I can get means by year simply by `aggregate(area~ year, df, mean)` but I would like to practice pipes instead.

Thank you!

---

```
# Dummy data
set.seed(13)
df<-data.frame(year = rep(c(1:5), each = 5),
               area = rep(c(3:7), each = 5) + rnorm(1))

# Calculate means. 
# Neither `mean(df$area)`, `mean("area")` or `mean[area]` does not work. How to call the column correctly?

df %>% 
  split(df$year) %>%
  mean
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This?

```
 df %>% 
      group_by(year) %>% 
      summarise(Mean=mean(area))
```

Comment: It was a case of timing I guess. I posted my answer before seeing his. Should I delete it?

Comment: I think it would be in the same time when I updated.  You don't have to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

We need to extract the column from the `list` of `data.frame`s in `split`.  One option is to loop through the `list` with `map`, and `summarise` the  'area'.

```
df %>% 
   split(.$year) %>% 
   map_df(~ .x %>% 
             summarise(area = mean(area)))
```